# one to one and onto meaning

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

If $T$ is a linear transformation and is said to be one to one or onto- this only makes sense when we specify what domain and range is right? 
$T: V \rightarrow V$ may not be onto or one to one
but $T: V \rightarrow Im(T)$ is certainly onto and may or may not be one to one.
Is this right?

Comment: Yes. $\,\!\,\!$

Comment: When we say $T$ is a linear transformation, we have to talk about its domain and range, just as we do for general mappings. Given $T: V \to W$,  we can construct $T': V \to R(T)$, which is regarded as a different linear transformation, where you have pointed out, $T$ may not be onto but $T'$ must be.

Comment: It will be onto, but not one to one if the $T$'s are the same mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this needs a bit more clarification:

1. Your question is really about **functions** in general and not related to linear algebra.
2. Any function should be thought of as a triple $(f, X, Y)$ which is normally denoted by $f\colon X\to Y$. In other words, whenever you're talking about a function, you should have fixed (at least implicitly) a domain and a codomain for it. Therefore, strictly speaking writing $$f\colon X\to \operatorname{Im} f$$
   is not correct, because once you change the codomain you're dealing with a new function and you'd better use a different letter, say $g$, to denote it to avoid confusion. Of course, when you get comfortable with these notions, you can get a little sloppy and say things like ``any function is onto its image,'' etc.

PS I just noticed that SRX has made the same point 2 in his comment earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. We can "make" a linear transformation onto by restricting the codomain to the image of the transformation.